# modify the classpath dynamically

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, urlclassloader

I want to add the configuration files under `/home/nameuser/.myProject/conf` to the classpath at runtime.

I tried using `URLClassLoader` but without success.

```
URL[] url={new URL("file://foo")};
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(url);
```

or

```
ClassLoader currentThreadClassLoader
 = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

// Add the conf dir to the classpath
// Chain the current thread classloader
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader
 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("mtFile").toURL()},
                      currentThreadClassLoader);

// Replace the thread classloader - assumes
// you have permissions to do so
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
```

Comment: Use the classloader to [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) the target class and use reflection to utilize it.

Comment: my files are not class but configuration files

Comment: Do you have the following in your code: `URL[] url={new URL("file:///home/nameuser/.myProject/conf/")};`?

Comment: yes, it does not work

Comment: @user1842570 If you want to use a ClassLoader to dynamically load classes, you must load the classes via it. The Thread context ClassLoader is just a thread-local getter/setter. It does not automatically make types visible that wouldn't normally be visible. Nothing does.

Comment: I don't want load class, I want load file conf

Comment: @Toisur You should be able to use `ClassLoader.getResource()` on the new classloader then.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded

thank you to Darcy Qiu is good `URL[] url={new URL("file:///home/nameuser/.myProject/conf/")};` I had to do and not `URL[] url={new URL("file:///home/nameuser/.myProject/conf/myfile")};`